# date validator clears date field after validation check

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs and js. I am working on a date validation code frmo a date picker. 
below is the code that does the validation. problem is, when we pick a date and try to update it clears the whole date field as shown in gif link here :-
[click here for date validation sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbBDR.gif)

below is the code that does the date validation.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name fromCriterion
 *
 * @description Converts a criterion's value into a value that can be used for the specified type of field.
 *
 * @param{String} criterion The criterion's string value, generally taken from the report state criteria
 * @param{String} type The type of the field which will use the criterion's value
 *
 * @returns{Object} The native object needed for a field, converted from a report criterion
 */
fromCriterion: function(criterion, type){
    if(angular.isDefined(criterion)){
        switch (type){
        case 'boolean':
            return criterion === '1';
        case 'compact_date':
            if (criterion.length > 9 && criterion.length < 11)
            return criterion !== "" && criterion !== "Invalid date" ? DateService.castTimeToUtcDate(moment(criterion, 'MMDDYYYY')): "";
        case 'inline_list':
        case 'inline_list_search':
            return criterion.split(',');
        case 'integer':
            return !_.isNaN(criterion) ? parseInt(criterion) : undefined;
        case 'iso_date':
            return criterion !== "" && criterion !== "Invalid date"  ? DateService.castTimeToUtcDate(moment(criterion, 'YYYY-MM-DD')): "";
        case 'suggest':
            return criterion.toString();
        default:
            return criterion;
       }
    }

    return undefined;
},

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name toCriterion
 *
 * @description Converts the criterion value into a proper criterion string value,
 *              based on the type of the field that used the criterion.
 *
 * @param {Object} criterion The value of the field, which will be converted for
 *           storage within the report state criteria.
* @param {String} type The type of the field which interacted with the criteria.
*
 * @returns {String} The string which will be stored as a report criterion
 */
toCriterion: function(criterion, type){
                var parsedDate;
if (angular.isDefined(criterion)){
        switch (type){
        case 'boolean':
            return criterion ? '1': '0';
            break;
        case 'compact_date':
            return _.isDate(criterion) && criterion + "" !== "Invalid Date" ? DateService.formatDate(criterion, 'MMddyyyy'): '';
            break;
        case 'integer':
            return criterion ? criterion.toString() : '';
            break;
        case 'inline_list':
        case 'inline_list_search':
            return criterion.join();
            break;
        case 'iso_date':
            return _.isDate(criterion) && criterion + "" !== "Invalid Date" ? DateService.formatDate(criterion, 'yyyy-MM-dd'): '';
            break;
        case 'suggest':
            return parseInt(criterion);
            break;
        default:
            return criterion;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

What I want is, the date field should not become null as user tries to update it.

--

this is the html tag which takes input

```
 <div name="communicationForm">
                  …
      …
                <hh-report-field field-name="MinContactDate" report-state-promise="reportStatePromise"></hh-report-field>
                 <hh-report-field field-name="MaxContactDate" report-state-promise="reportStatePromise"></hh-report-field>
             </div>
```

below is the hh-report-field.js code:

```
 angular.module('hhReport')
     .controller('hhReportFieldController', [function(){

         var ctrl = this;
     }])
    .directive('hhReportField', ['$compile', 'FieldCriteriaService', 'FieldInjectionService',      'FieldCriteriaMapService',
                                  function($compile, FieldCriteriaService, FieldInjectionService, FieldCriteriaMapService){
         return {
             retrict: 'E',
             bindToController: {
                 reportStatePromise: '='
             },
             controller: 'hhReportFieldController',
             controllerAs: 'reportFieldCtrl',
             require: '^hhRefinementBar',
             scope: true,
             templateUrl: '/static/report/scripts/directives/hh-report-field.html',
             transclude: true,
             link: function(scope, element, attrs, refinementBar, transclude){
                 var reportFieldCtrl = scope.reportFieldCtrl;

                 reportFieldCtrl.reportStatePromise.then(function(state){
                     reportFieldCtrl.reportState = state;

                     if (!attrs.fieldName){
                         throw Error('Report fields must have a field-name attribute. If they use a variable, their field-name must match the variable.');
                     }

                     var criterion = state.criteria[attrs.fieldName];

                                    var getBoolValue = state.get_criteria_field_property_boolean;

                                 fieldProps = state.get_criteria_field_properties(attrs.fieldName);

                                   if(!getBoolValue(fieldProps.hidden)) {
                                           var fieldConfig = {
                             fieldName: attrs.fieldName,
                             attributes: {}
                         };

                         // throw if type is not provided from criteria_fields
                         // (this shouldn't really happen)
                         if(!fieldProps.field_type) {
                             throw('There is no type set for : ' + attrs.fieldName + ' in criteria_fields for this report.');
                         } else {
                             fieldConfig.criteriaType = FieldCriteriaService.getClassicFieldType(fieldProps.field_type);
                             var fieldMap = FieldCriteriaMapService.getFieldMapByType(fieldConfig.criteriaType);

                             fieldConfig.fieldType = fieldMap.type;

                             if (fieldMap.attributes){
                                 angular.extend(fieldConfig.attributes, fieldMap.attributes);
                             }

                             if (angular.isFunction(fieldMap.ctrlSetup)){
                                 fieldMap.ctrlSetup(scope.reportFieldCtrl, fieldProps, fieldConfig);
                             }

                             // Set the default based on either the config.xml, or the required default for a type.
                             if (criterion !== '' && criterion !== undefined && criterion !== null) {
                                 reportFieldCtrl.model = FieldCriteriaService.fromCriterion(state.criteria[attrs.fieldName], fieldConfig.criteriaType);
                             } else if(fieldProps.default){
                                 // defaults in config are handled like values from the report criteria
                                 reportFieldCtrl.model = FieldCriteriaService.fromCriterion(fieldProps.default, fieldConfig.criteriaType);
                             } else if (fieldMap.default){
                                 reportFieldCtrl.model = fieldMap.default;
                             } else {
                                 reportFieldCtrl.model = undefined;
                             }
                         }


                    fieldConfig.attributes['ng-required'] = getBoolValue(fieldProps.isrequired);

                    // just pull the label from the report config.xml display_name
                    // labelText is used by this directive, not passed to FieldService to get an Ext field
                    fieldConfig.label = fieldProps.display_name;

                    // Add in a description
                    fieldConfig.description = attrs.fieldDescription;

                    //TODO: Check if label-name is used in the reports and if it actually sets the label

                    // Add the model to our field's attributes.
                    fieldConfig.attributes['ng-model'] = 'reportFieldCtrl.model';

                    angular.forEach(attrs, function(v,k) {
                        if (k.startsWith('val')) {
                            fieldConfig.attributes[_.kebabCase(k.substr(3))] = v.replace(/\\/g, "");
                        }
                    });

                    // Chips freak out if you update constantly; therefore, update on blur.
                    // Need to allow invalid or else the model is never set and our validation doesn't occur
                    // Which, you know, means it will clear out your input without any warning. Bad UX. Thx Angular.
                    if(!FieldCriteriaService.isSearchableDropdownType(fieldConfig.fieldType)) {
                        fieldConfig.attributes['ng-model-options'] = '{debounce: 500, allowInvalid: true}';
                    }

                    scope.$watch('reportFieldCtrl.model', function(newModel){
                        // Set the criterion here, only if it has changed.
                        if (FieldCriteriaService.toCriterion(newModel, fieldConfig.criteriaType) !== state.criteria[attrs.fieldName]){
                            // Criteria are stored as strings for SQL queries.
                            // TODO: Ensure that toString works for each type of criteria,
                            // otherwise, we will need our own method here.
                            state.set_criterion(attrs.fieldName, FieldCriteriaService.toCriterion(newModel, fieldConfig.criteriaType));
                        }
                    });

                    scope.$watch(angular.bind(reportFieldCtrl.reportState, function(){
                        return this.criteria[attrs.fieldName];
                    }), function(newCriterion){
                        // change to use isNill once we upgrade to lodash 4.13
                        // if(_.isNil(newCriterion)) {
                        if (newCriterion !== undefined && newCriterion !== null){
                            reportFieldCtrl.model = FieldCriteriaService.fromCriterion(newCriterion, fieldConfig.criteriaType);
                        }
                    });

                    // Create the field here using attr.fieldType, similar to mapFieldType in grid
                    // Maybe make that a shared thing in core? Like a factory that returns a string
                    // built from it? Maybe...unless this gets form, then put it in form...
                    var reportField = element.find('.report-field');

                    reportField.append(FieldInjectionService(fieldConfig));

                    $compile(reportField)(scope);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Could you also show how it is being used with the input element?

Comment: sorry for late reply.I have updated above about input elements. let me know if it helps.